# Raster to vector data in GEE 'NOAA/GOES/16/FDCC' some wrong

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, goes-16

I can't transform the raster to vector in  'NOAA/GOES/16/FDCC'. I get the error `Buffer: Tile error: Can't transform (71.0,1451.0)`.

```
var ROI = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017').select("country_co").toList(6).get(4);
var dataset =  ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017').select("country_co")
var FeatureCo = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_co','US')).toList(6);
var USA = ee.Feature(ee.FeatureCollection([FeatureCo.get(5),FeatureCo.get(4),FeatureCo.get(2),FeatureCo.get(1)]).union().first());
var USA_collect = ee.FeatureCollection(USA);
USA = USA.geometry()
print(USA ,'USA ');
Map.addLayer(USA);
var geometry = USA;

function clip(image){
  var image = image.clip(USA);
  return image;
}

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/GOES/16/FDCC')
                      .filterDate('2020-09-05T13:00','2020-09-06T01:00');
                      
print(collection,'collection');
var collection_list = collection.toList(500);
var image = ee.Image(collection_list.get(30));
//image =  collection.max();
 
print(image);
var timeStamp = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format().slice(0,16);
print(timeStamp,'imageTime');
Map.setOptions("HYBRID");
// Select property of image.
var DQF = ee.Image(image).select('DQF').clip(USA);
var Temp= ee.Image(image).select('Temp').clip(USA);

print(DQF,'DQF');
print(Temp,'Temp');
Map.addLayer(Temp, {color:'red'}, 'Temp');
Export.image.toDrive({image:DQF,maxPixels:1e13,description:'DQF20200905_1531', fileFormat:'GeoTiff'});
Export.image.toDrive({image:Temp,maxPixels:1e13, description:'Temp20200905_1531',fileFormat:'GeoTiff'});

var DQFVectors = DQF.reduceToVectors({
  geometry: USA,
  crs: DQF.projection(), // remove .first()
  geometryType: 'polygon'
}); 
Map.addLayer(DQFVectors, {color:'red'}, 'DQFVectors');
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem, because `DQF` don't have  crs, so add

```
var crs= 'EPSG:4326'; //add projection
```

then add crs and scale in

```
var firetempVectors = firetemp.reduceToVectors({
  //geometry: USA,
  crs: crs, // add projection
  scale:2000,//add scale
  geometryType: 'polygon'
});
```

Ccode link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2F2395380880%2Fmethod_Code%3AGEOS_DownLoad